# Count the Number of Entries in an Ecto Repository

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Whats the quickest way to see the number of entries in my database? I'd like to see the number of posts in my posts/index view.

Say I have a Post model and a bunch of posts saved in my database. In Rails I could do something like this in a view file:

```
<h1><%= @posts.length %> Posts</h1>
```

or

```
<h1><%= @posts.size %> Posts</h1>
```

or

```
<h1><%= @posts.count %> Posts</h1>
```

What's the Phoenix Framework/Elixir equivalent?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you've already loaded the posts in memory in your controller using `Repo.all`, you can use `length/1` to count the number of items in the list. This is equivalent to `.length` in Ruby/Rails.

```
length(@posts)
```

If you want to run the count query in the database instead, you can do:

```
Repo.one(from p in Post, select: count("*"))
```

You can also add `where:` filter to the query to restrict the posts to e.g. created by a specific user. This is equivalent to doing `.count` in Rails.

Answer (score 78):

The options that [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685025/219743) has provided are both correct and should be used for Ecto 1.x.

In Ecto 2.0 you can use [Repo.aggregate/4](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/57ea6bbb60e9af1886e306f9be47d73d7436daf9/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L335)

```
Repo.aggregate(Post, :count, :id)
```

Comment: This one also helps to build composable queries