# Insert a count of User on the Index page

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I display the number (COUNT) of `User` entries on the index page 
of this little Phoenix application?

```
mix phoenix.new my_app
cd my_app
mix ecto.create
mix phoenix.gen.html User users name:string
mix ecto.migrate
```

**web/controllers/page_controller.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.PageController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "index.html"
  end
end
```

**web/templates/page/index.html.eex**

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2>Number of Users: </p>
</div>
```

In Rails I'd insert a `@user_count = User.all.count` in the controller and do a `<%= @user_count %>` in the view.

What is the proper MVC way to do that in Phoenix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the Number of Entries in an Ecto Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683238/count-the-number-of-entries-in-an-ecto-repository)

Comment: Would you mind giving me the code example I need to use in the controller and template? I don't have to do anything in the view, do I? I'm still stuck in the MVC logic of Phoenix. I know it's an absolute newbie question.

Comment: `user_count = Repo.one(from u in User, select: count("*")); render conn, "index.html", user_count: user_count` and then use `@user_count` in the template.

Answer (score 1):

**web/controllers/page_controller.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.PageController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller
  alias MyApp.User

  def index(conn, _params) do
    user_count = Repo.one(from u in User, select: count("*"))
    render conn, "index.html", user_count: user_count
  end
end
```

**web/templates/page/index.html.eex**

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2>Number of Users: <%= @user_count %></p>
</div>
```

Thanks to @dogbert for the solution.